# How to persist cloned entity object in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to clone an entity record along with the relationships it holds among other entities. I have successfully cloned some entity objects but this one to many entity relationship has challenged me. I have reviewed similar questions regarding the error message I have been given without progress to the challenge.

The correct records are queried out, looped through and cloned then stored in an array. I have tried to persist the array but get error

> EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object,
>   array given

I then tried to encode the array and persist but I get error

> The class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse' was not
>   found in the chain configured namespaces NameOfBundle\Entity.

This below code is in my controller

```
    $quoteItemAddWorkCollection = $em->getRepository('UniflyteBundle:QuoteItemAdditionalWork')->findBy($params);
    $quoteItemDeliverableCollection = $em->getRepository('UniflyteBundle:QuoteItemDeliverable')->findBy($params);

    if (!empty($quoteItemAddWorkCollection)) {
        $quoteItemAddWorkArray = [];
        foreach ($quoteItemAddWorkCollection as $quoteItemAddWorkItem) {
            $quoteItemAddWorkItemClone = clone $quoteItemAddWorkItem;
            array_push($quoteItemAddWorkArray, $quoteItemAddWorkItemClone);
        }
        $quoteItemAddWorkCollection = new JsonResponse($quoteItemAddWorkArray);

        $em->persist($quoteItemAddWorkCollection);
```

I can't persist an array, I have to encode it to json first I believe. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of Doctrine concepts here. In terms of Doctrine, each entity:

- `UniflyteBundle:QuoteItemAdditionalWork`

  and
- `UniflyteBundle:QuoteItemDeliverable`

  , and any of its relationships, could get persisted, using a configuration named [Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

To get this into work, any **In-Memory** object, MUST be an instance of a **managed entity class**.

There is not such a magic in Doctrine, to persist so many unknown objects at once. You may persist them, one-by-one inside a loop:

```
foreach ($quoteItemAddWorkCollection as $quoteItemAddWorkItem) {

    $quoteItemAddWorkItemClone = clone $quoteItemAddWorkItem;
    $quoteItemAddWorkItemClone->setId(null);

    // Set relationships here ...

    $em->persist($quoteItemAddWorkItemClone);
}
```

Keep in mind to set any required relationships, before persisting your new cloned objects.

If you want to use, one persist, you can assign their relationships, inside a loop:

```
foreach ($quoteItemAddWorkCollection as $quoteItemAddWorkItem) {

    $quoteItemAddWorkItemClone = clone $quoteItemAddWorkItem;
    $quoteItemAddWorkItemClone->setId(null);

    $someParentCollection->add($quoteItemAddWorkItemClone);
}

$em->persist($someParentCollection);
```

the latter method, needs you to set `cascade` on mapping configuration:

```
class SomeParent
{
    // @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuoteItemAdditionalWork", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
    private $quoteItemAddWork;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight. I did not fully understand the persist functionality and potential. Persisting each clone in the loop worked great.

Comment: using `persist`, you are telling Doctrine: *Hey! please keep track of any changes made to this entity*. So you need to call it ONLY ONCE per entity.